# Searching Thousands of Files in a Directory using a CSV List

Tags: performance, powershell, glob

I'm using Powershell 5.0 and I have a `.CSV` file with a list siebelid that I want to search for (approx: 5000) and I want to search through each folder and subfolder on a server for any file that contains that list item (siebelid) in the file name. i.e filename: 32444167.pdf or 32444167.pdf.metadata.properties.xml

Example CSV file:

```
32444167,ACME,4/15/2013
27721071,ACME,4/15/2013
27721072,ACME,4/15/2013
```

I am filtering on `*.PDF` and `*.XML`. Then I want to copy the found files to a destination folder on the same server. The problem is, I have hundreds of thousands of files in the folder and subfolders. The Code I wrote seems to take a long time to run upto several days. I am not an expert and believe I have not written the most efficient Powershell script. Any help would be appreciated.

Basically, the code works but it extremely slow when processing through a folder that has hundreds of thousands of files. It seems in efficient to call the `Get-Childitem` each time I'm getting a new item from the list.

```
$PDFExtension = '.pdf'
$XMLExtension = '.pdf.metadata.properties.xml'
$source = 'C:\Temp\CSVtoXML'
$destination = 'C:\Temp\FindFiles\'                                                           #' 
$strGetDate = get-date -UFormat “%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”
$log = $destination + "FileCopyLog.txt"

$FileList = import-csv “C:\Temp\FindFiles\test.csv” -Delimiter "," -Header 'siebelId', 'companyCode', 'receivedDate'
$GetFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -path $source -Recurse -File -include *.xml, *.pdf ) | select -First 100000

ForEach ($item in $FileList){
 $siebelId = $($item.siebelId) + $PDFExtension
 $XMLFile = $($item.siebelId) + $XMLExtension

 $FilterFiles = @($GetFiles) | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $siebelId -or $_.name -eq $XMLFile} #|  Out-File $destination"FileCopyLog.csv"
 #write-host "Filtered Files: " $FilterFiles

 ForEach ($file in $FilterFiles){

   $fileBase = $file.BaseName
   $fileExt = $file.Extension

   write-host "file: " $fileBase$fileExt

   If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($file))) {
       if(!(Test-Path -Path $Destination$fileBase$fileExt)) {
            copy-item $file -destination $destination   # Copies files
            write-host "File: [" $file "] has Been Copied! to " $Destination `n`r -ForegroundColor yellow
            $strGetDate = get-date -UFormat “%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”
            $LogValue = $strGetDate + ': ' + "Source: [" + $file + "] Destination: " + $Destination
            Add-Content -Path $log -Value $LogValue
       } else
       {
            write-host "File: [" $file "] already exsits in destination folder" `n`r -ForegroundColor yellow
            $strGetDate = get-date -UFormat “%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”
            $LogValue = $strGetDate + ': ' + "File: [" + $file + "] already exsits in destination folder! "
            Add-Content -Path $log -Value $LogValue 
       }

   }else{
       write-host "No File was copied!" `n`r -ForegroundColor red
   }
 }
}

write-host 'Script has completed' -ForegroundColor green
```

The expected results I'm looking for is to have this process within a couple of hours rather than several days.

Answer (score 1):

### Instead of looping the files, filter them.

Amended to use ".pdf.metadata.properties.xml" instead of XML, and mattch those by srtipping '.pdf.metadata.properties' from the "Basename" of the files we found

**edit**

Also put in more of your script to reduce time taken in the copy process, by generating a list of destination files and then filtering the files we'l copy by fi

```
$Exts =@('.pdf','.pdf.metadata.properties.xml')

$source = 'C:\Temp\CSVtoXML'
$destination = 'C:\Temp\FindFiles\'                                                           #' 
$strGetDate = get-date -UFormat “%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”
$log = "$($destination)FileCopyLog.txt"

$SiebelIDFile="$($destination)test.csv"
$SiebelIDImport = import-csv $SiebelIDFile -Delimiter "," -Header 'siebelId', 'companyCode', 'receivedDate'

$SRC_Matched_Exts = $(  $Exts | % { Get-ChildItem -path $source -Recurse -File -Filter $_  } )


# Presto we can filter the list using the Siebel IDs


$Results = $SRC_Matched_Exts | ? { $( $($_.basename) -replace '.pdf.metadata.properties','' ) -in $($SiebelIDImport.SiebelID) }

# Confirm results by outputting first 1000
$Results | select -first 100 | FT -property BaseName, FullName -Auto 

# Get Destination Files to compare:
$Dst_Matched_Exts = $(  $Exts | % { Get-ChildItem -path $Destiation -Recurse -File -Filter $_  } )

# Filter to only the Source files notin the destination:
$Src_Files_MissingFromDst = $Results | ? { $_.basename -notin $( $Dst_Matched_Exts.basename ) }
$Src_Files_AlreadyInDs = $Results | ? { $_.basename -notin $Src_Files_MissingFromDst.basename }


# Output some of the Files we won't Copy because they already exist in dst:
Write-host "
 Output some of the Files we won't Copy because they already exist in dst:

$($Src_Files_AlreadyInDst | select -first 100 | FT -property BaseName, FullName -Auto | Out-String)" -ForegroundColor red

# Output some of the Files we will Copy:
Write-host "
 Output some of the Files we will Copy:

$Src_Files_MissingFromDst | select -first 100 | FT -property BaseName, FullName -Auto | Out-String )" -ForegroundColor yellow

$Count=0
# Loop Files and Copy them to Destination:
$Src_Files_MissingFromDst | %{
  $Count+=1
  copy-item $($_.Fullname) -destination $destination   # Copies files
  Add-Content -Path $log -Value "$(Get-Date -UFormat `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`")`: Source File # $Count: [$($file)] Destination: $Destination"
  # Update the copy progress every 10 files
  IF ( ! [bool]( $Count % 10 ) -or $Count -eq $($Src_Files_MissingFromDst.count)  ) {
    Write-Progress -Activity "======== Copying to $Destination" -Status "## $([math]::round( $(($Count/$($Src_Files_MissingFromDst.count))*100), 1))% Complete!" -PercentComplete $([math]::round( $(($Count/$($Src_Files_MissingFromDst.count))*100), 1))
    write-host "File # $Count: [ $file ] has Been Copied to  $Destination " -ForegroundColor Green
  }

}
```

now you can write your filecopy/move based off the collection of matched file - and it would make sense to use a parallel process to speed that up.

Loops are always slower than filtering by select statements, also using the in-line filter on the command is almost always a better path than filtering the results as the filtering happens at the lower level while collecting the data.

Comment: With the existing `$XMLExtension = '.pdf.metadata.properties.xml'` checking for only `$_.BaseName` won't work.

Comment: @LotPings You're right, I only used *.pdf when writing this on the train, could fix with a replace when I have time.

Comment: Thank you! I'm running this now and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @user1003713 You're welcome.  I just noticed that the Output of the first 100 files to copy / not to copy are not going to work right because I left off `| Out-String`  i amended that int he code now.  Any other issues let me know I wrote this on my phone during my commute and off moments so I might have some dumb things like that which could be addressed quickly.

Comment: Worked Great! It took the processing time from days down to 1 hour or less. Thanks for your help. I did however, have an issue with getting the Progress code to work. Not sure what was not working there but all others worked great.

Comment: @user1003713 Glad to help, I through the process loop on at the last minute probably did something dumb when creating it, and I hate the because they slowdown the processing immensely, which is why I tried to call it less frequently probably just made a mistake in hat logic or syntax, but just leave it off, it was just a flourish.

Comment: @user1003713  Ahh, I scoped it out, I had the Logical test to find when the count was divisible by 10 wrong.  It should be `IF ( ! [bool]( $Count % 10 ) -or $Count -eq $($Src_Files_MissingFromDst.count)  ) { `  Instead of   `IF ([bool]( (! $Count % 10 ) -or ($Count -eq $($Src_Files_MissingFromDst.count) ) ) {`  -- Looks liek that was just a fat fingering on my phone.  I have fixed it in the answer above as well. in case you or others would like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(Get-ChildItem -path $source -Recurse -File -Filter *.xml
  Get-ChildItem -path $source -Recurse -File -Filter *.pdf)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The matching and filtering above works well when the BaseName is the same as the SiebelID in the .CSV file but when I have a file with a base name of .pdf.metadata.propteries.xml it doesn't. I need to figure out how to parse the basename and match that to my import file.

Comment: @user1003713  I believe you meant to respond to my comment.  I only was searching on .pdf, so I'll amend my answer fot this,   My answer is the one beginning with `Instead of looping the files, filter them.`

Answer (score 0):

As the `siebelID` seems to have 8 digits, you could use that to select files.

I'm unsure what's more efficient:

- crawling the tree twice (for each extension) or
- only once using a Where-Object and a Regular Expression which in one go extracts the number and checks for presence in `$Filelist`

The output should be reduced to the absolute necessary to speed up processing.

The following script also removes redundancy in creating `$LogValue`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\26\SO_57658091.ps1
$source = 'Q:\Test\2019' # 'C:\Temp\CSVtoXML'    # 
$target = 'A:\Test\2019' # 'C:\Temp\FindFiles\'  # 
$log = Join-Path $target  "FileCopyLog.txt"

$RE = '^(?<siebelID>\d{8})\.pdf(\.metadata\.properties\.xml)?'
$FileList = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\FindFiles\test.csv" -Header siebelId,companyCode,receivedDate

Get-ChildItem -path $source -Recurse -File -Filter '*.pdf*' |
  Where-Object {($_.Name -match $RE ) -and
                ($Matches.siebelID -in $FileList.siebelID)} | 
ForEach-Object{
    if(!(Test-Path (Join-Path $target $_.Name))) {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $target   # Copies files
        $Copied = 'copied to {0}' -f $target
    } else {
        $Copied = 'present in destination'
    }
    $LogValue = '{0}: File: [{1}] {2}' -f (Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),$_.Name,$Copied
    # $LogValue  # optionally output, but that slows down.
    Add-Content -Path $log -Value $LogValue 
}

write-host 'Script has completed' -ForegroundColor green
```

A slightly adapted version to search through my test folder with stored SO scripts which happen to also have an 8 digit number yields this `FileCopyLog.txt`

```
2019-08-26 17:46:03: File: [SO_55464728.ps1] copied to A:\Test\2019
2019-08-26 17:46:03: File: [SO_55569099.ps1] copied to A:\Test\2019
2019-08-26 17:46:03: File: [SO_55575835.cmd] copied to A:\Test\2019
2019-08-26 17:46:03: File: [SO_55575543.ps1] copied to A:\Test\2019
```